# Why did they include the air pocket in Justice League films only?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, aquaman, zack-snyders-justice-league

In *Aquaman* (2018), underwater characters didn't create the air pocket to have conversations but in *Justice League* (2017) and its director's cut underwater characters create the air pocket to have conversations:

[image]
[image]

<sub>These are the images of interior (right) and exterior (left) of the air pocket in the **Zack Snyder's Justice League (2021)**.</sub>

Comment: The air pockets were first seen in the theatrical cut of _Justice League_, during the scene where Aquaman and Mera confront Steppenwolf.

Comment: @LogicDictates I edited my title of this question and its body.

Comment: Different directors + different styles. I remember the pocket being mocked after Justice League, James Wan probably didn't want his movie ridiculed too

Comment: I think James Wan tried to explain the importance of air capsules. It was for some privacy for their conversation if they wanted. Otherwise they could just have normal conversation under water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was Zack Snyder's decision for *Justice League*. He was apparently perfectly happy with having magical flying superheroes fighting intergalactic insects led by a evil [brillo pad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oB4i.jpg), but thought that the idea of people talking underwater was silly and illogical.

> I invented that because I don’t like talking underwater. It makes no sense. I believe Atlanteans’ underwater language would be a series of clicks and squeaks, never got a chance to work it out.
>
> <sub><sup>[Zack Snyder - Via Twitter](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2485701/check-out-willem-dafoes-deleted-justice-league-scenes-in-new-snyder-cut-images)</sup></sub>

James Wan, on the other hand, had a different thought and decided that his Aquaman characters would have their lungs filled with water, allowing them to speak underwater. **No reason was given for this change of direction, other than it purely being a directorial choice.**

> "Just from a practical standpoint, people ask me, when they talk, 'Is it bubbles that come out of their mouth?'" Wan explained. "No, 'cause there's no air in your lungs, so there wouldn't be any bubbles, right? Because you don't do that, right? And, so, then, in that sequence, where you saw Mera open up this air pocket to suck Orm away from Arthur, help him out, now, when he's breathing, the first thing he does is he using the air pockets, where he could get out all of the water that's in his lungs."
>
> <sub><sup>['Aquaman': Why Atlanteans Vomit When Out of Water](https://comicbook.com/dc/news/aquaman-atlantean-water-bubbles-talk-vomit-air/)</sup></sub>